# How to pull from one Github repository to multiple local repositories?

Tags: git, github, pull

I have a WordPress parent theme and multiple WordPress website (all on the same filesystem) that use it. So how do I make sure with Git that each instance of the parent theme is synced with the version on Github? Without having to pull each instance individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked how to keep multiple local repository clones up-to-date without having to pull each instance individually. Carl-Eric has addressed how to efficiently *store* multiple repositories on your filesystem.  Here are some suggestions on keeping them up-to-date:

One solution would be to set up a `post-merge` hook in one of the repositories that iterates across the others and performs the `pull` operation:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset GIT_DIR
for repo in /path/to/repo1 /path/to/repo2; do
   ( cd $repo && git pull)
done
```

The `post-merge` script is run after a `git pull` operation.

Having said that, the simplest option would be to have a single clone of the repository and then symlink to it from the other locations.

Comment: I think you might be right with regards to the use of symbolic links. However I'll see if there are any more suggestions before I implement anything. Thanks you.

Comment: I had overlooked the "only one pull" requirement. I think the last sentence here nails it. Clone once and symlink.

Answer (score 0):

First you clone the github repo once to your local machine.

Then you can continue in two ways:

- you can simply do a local deep copy of that clone. All settings will be identical, the copies will all have their `origin` remote pointing to github. You will waste some disk space though, since all copies will obviously have the entire repo in them.
- or, to save disk space, you can clone that local repo as often as you need. Git will try and reuse the repository objects as much as possible by hardlinking them. In this case you will likely have to adjust the remotes you're using, since `origin` will point to the local repository by default, rather than to Github.

Comment: This assumes that they're on the same filesystem. He did mention that the original is on github.

Comment: My assumption was that he had a local clone of the github repo. Edited the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: I didn't know about the hardlinks optimisation. Thanks +1

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question about how to keep multiple local copies of the repository up-to-date without ahving to run `git pull` in each of them invidually.